# Hazelcast stream aggregation and other calc is performed on node or client

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-caching

We are using hazelcast in our project, i would like to know that whatever calculation we do runs on the hazelcast node or the client itself

For eg.

```
Imap map = client.get("data");
map.values().stream....
```

In this example does it get whole map from hzc (hazelcast) or its just a reference and when i actually use terminal function in the stream it goes to hzc node and performs operation and get the data?

Answer (score 0):

`map.values()` will fetch all the values from all the nodes to the client. Please review [Fast Aggregations](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#fast-aggregations) if you need to do the calculations on member side.

Comment: Thank you so much, ideally we will be able to do all operation that we could do using stream in fast aggregation?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, you can use lambdas in your aggregator implementations.

Comment: Could we use hzc jet and that will also run on members ? if yes what about performance which one is better jet or fast aggregator ?

Comment: Hazelcast Jet will also distribute the calculation among members. The performance depends on the use case. I would definitely suggest you give it a try for your use case.

Comment: To conclude the thread jet was really faster than fast agg when the dataset was huge. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also please consider accepting answers to your open questions that you are satisfied with - you have a lot of open ones and we try to track if there are any unanswered questions about Hazelcast & Jet